# DFTB+ -> Invalid parser version

Tags: conda

Maybe I'll help someone with this:
Got this issue:

`dftb+: error while loading shared libraries: libgsl.so.25`

Same problem [discussed here](https://mailman.zfn.uni-bremen.de/pipermail/dftb-plus-user/2023/004072.html)
After horrible hours found this solution:

`conda install gsl=2.5.0`

But now I have the next problem with DFTB+ -> Invalid parser version.
Maybe someone knows how to fix this problem with DFTB+ Parser? I'm trying recipes from [recipes](https://dftbplus-recipes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html).

I'm freshman with this conda and DFTB+ business, and I have no idea why new installed dftb+ software doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Just put :
`ParserOptions { ParserVersion = 9 }`
It helped.
Now  I got this:
ERROR!
-> SK file 'O-O.skf' does not exist'
this can be solved with `./scripts/get_slakos` from recipes folder.